# Softphone client to use with g729

Tags: sip, asterisk

Is there a softphone ( opensource, freeware, or trial version) with G.729 codec ? I just need to make a call and see how it goesthrough a sip protocol on Asteriks.
Thank you on advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try Microsip sip client [microsip.org](http://microsip.org)

Its opensource and the binary version has G729 codec as built in . So you will able to check how the codec work.

Answer (score 1):

Im using [MicroSIP](https://www.microsip.org)  open source portable SIP softphone based on PJSIP stack for Windows OS.
contain this  codecs:

- Opus@24kHz
- G.711 A-law (PCMA)
- G.711 u-law (PCMU)
- G.722@16kHz
- G.723@8kHz
- **G.729@8kHz**
- iLBC@8kHz
- GSM@8kHz
- AMR@8kHz
- AMR-WB@16kHz
- Speex@8,16,32kHz,
- SILK@8,12,16,24kHz
- and Linear   PCM@44kHz, including stereo.

Answer (score 0):

Zoiper supports g.729 in its non-free versions (for example, Zoiper Classic Biz).  Given the patents and licensing surrounding g.729 however, that's hardly surprising.

[Zoiper Order Page](http://shop.zoiper.com)

Answer (score 0):

Unfrotanly your request teoreticaly not posible. Reason: g729 codec stil under royality. So anyone tried to offer opensource variant will brake royality law.

Comment: well, as far as i understand I can use it for researching and learning goals